# Asymptotic bound in induction

Tags: induction, asymptotics

I actually thought about this after reading the proof for the Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem (though it is not necessarily related).

> Let us define a series: $a_1,...,a_n$  , where:
>   $$a_{i+1} = a_i + \log{n}$$
>   and: $$a_1=\log{n}$$
>   Obviously we get:
>   $a_n = n\log{n}$.

However, let us define the following inductive process:

> We will try to prove $a_i = O(\log{n})$ for $i=1,...,n$.
>
> The induction basis is pretty straight forward, we get $a_1 = \log{n}
>  = O(\log{n})$.
>
> Now, let's assume correctness for $j\le i$ and let's prove for $i+1$.
>   Since by induction hypothesis we get $a_i = O(\log{n})$, we get that
>   $a_{i+1} = a_i + \log{n} = O(\log{n}) + \log{n} = O(\log{n})$.
>
> So by proving the induction, we conclude that: $$a_n = O(\log{n})$$

This is **obviously** wrong, but where is the mistake in this induction? I guess it has something to do with the asymptotic bounds, but if the the basis is correct, and the inductive step (based *only* on the induction hypothesis) is correct, the induction should be too. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why this argument is wrong?

Comment: One thing I noted is that you mess up the indices a little bit. Since $a_m = m\log n=\OOO(m)$.

Comment: @StanTendijck not sure about your comment on the indices (the mathjax didn't parse, and I didn't use an $m$ index during my proof), but for your first comment, this is wrong since $n\log{n} \ne O(\log{n})$

Comment: I am sorry, what I wanted to say is that $a_n$ is indeed equal to $n\log n$. However, $a_m$ is not equal to $m\log m$ but equal to $m\log n$ which is of order $m$.

Comment: You can prove that by induction $a_i \leq C i$ (with $C=\log n$).

Comment: @StanTendijck I understand that, but the induction hypothesis I described is that for every $m\in [1,n]$ , $a_m = O(\log{n})$, and then I prove it with induction. My question is - where am I wrong there? Thanks

Comment: I think that that is actually true, since you let $n$ to be bounded. And as I recall, the definition of $a_n = O(f(n))$, is that there exist a constant $C$ such that for every $n$ (maybe even bigger than some $N$), $a_n\leq C f(n)$. Hence, if you have a bounded index set, it is difficult to actually use this order symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $n\in\mathbb{N^+}$ you can define the sequence $\{a_k\}$
$$
\begin{cases}
a_{k+1}(n)=a_k(n)+\log n \\
a_1(n)=\log n
\end{cases}
\implies a_k(n)=k\log n \quad\forall k\in\mathbb{N^+}
$$

Notice that the expression "$a_k= O(\log n)$" makes no sense because the value of $n$ is fixed. The asymptotic behaviour of $a_k$ is $O(k)$.

Now, for every fixed value of $k$, consider the sequence $\{b_n\}$ defined by
$$b_n(k)\colon=a_k(n)=k\log n \quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N^+}$$

Of course $b_n=k\log n=O(\log n)\quad\forall k\in\mathbb{N^+}$.

The sequence $\{b_n\}$ must not be confused with the different sequence $\{c_n\}$:
$$ c_n\colon= a_n(n)=b_n(n)=n\log n\ne O(\log n) $$

In this case both $k$ and $n$ grow to infinity and their values are not independent.

When you write "$a_n$" it's ambiguous: do you mean $b_n$ or $c_n$?
This is what you need to clarify in your proof.